# Gedit uses high CPU (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: xorg, gedit

I used gedit on Ubuntu for my everyday life. Previously it is fine, but some weeks ago a strange thing happens. It consumes high CPU. 
I disable all plugins, and monitor the CPU usage. You can see in screenshot below with its htop monitoring process.

What is the possible cause? I used 3.18 version, and I downgraded to Gedit 3.10 and the problem still persists. I change from lightdm to gdm3 (as the xorg used lightm), the problem also still persist.

The high CPU usually followed by xorg process, both consuming > 60 % each.
Recently I just moved from synaptics to libinput, but I think it is not the cause. My machine is macbook pro, mid 2012.

I dive into system log and nothing strange.

Any helps will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem. The culprit is **fcitx**. How can I know? As you can see in screenshot above (top/htop is the best tool to diagnose), after gedit the most CPU-hugry are xorg (with lightdm), compiz and fcitx. I changed from lightdm to gdm3 with no luck. I skipped compiz as the probability of making lag is small. From previous googling, I ever read that fcitx also causing hang in a case. This probably happens to me, too.

Then, I search `Language Support` in the dash. When I open it, it asks to update. Then I see it updated my `libfcitx`. After finish updating, I open my gedit, and, it works normally again!

If you encounter this problem (gEdit slow due to high CPU consumption) you may have either the same or different causes. Just investigate with top/htop, and see what apps causing it. Scan and investigate it one by one, from the highest CPU consumption.  The normal CPU consumption for an app about 5-10% (except chromium and high computation program).